# Getting the id of the object populating the Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The question is simple but I couldn't find any solution. I have got a SQLite table with "id" and "name" as columns. I needed to show in a spinner only the name (I did it), but, I want to get the Id of the object that is showed in the spinner only by name. Is there any way it can be done?

DatabaseHelper.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL1 + "       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 + " TEXT);";

db.execSQL(createTable);
}
public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);

    Log.d(Tag, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {

        return true;
    }
}

public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public void AddData(String newEntry){
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

    if (insertData){
        toastMessage("Data Succesfully entered");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Oops! Something went wrong");
    }

    loadSpinnerData();

}

    private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

The code is working fine, I copied what I think is the necessary things.

Comment: post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

You could determine the id based upon the label, BUT only if the label is unique, by add a new method say `getLabelId` e.g.

```
public long getLabelId(String label) {
    long rv = -1; //<<<< default return if nothing found
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "your_label_column_name" + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{label};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst) {
        rv = cursor.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("your_id_column");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- obviously you would have to change your_.... to appropriate values.

You could create a complimentary array that holds the id, so that the nth element of the complimentary array holds the id for the nth element of the List returned from the `getAllLabels` method.

You could create a class say Label that has members for both the label and the id and use that as the source of the Spinner.

Or you could use a CursorAdapter rather than an ArrayAdapter.

To use the latter you would only need to return a Cursor from the `getAllLabels` method. e.g. :-

```
public Cursor getAllLabels(){

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

- **NOTE!!!** CursorAdapters require that the **`id`** column is named **`_id`** (`BaseColumns._ID` can be used). So to utilise this method you would need to change the column id name to **`_id`**, if it is not named this already.

along with :-

```
Cursor csr = getAllLabels();
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    csr, //<<<< The Cursor to source the Spinner
    new String[]{"your_label_column_name"}, //<<<< The FROM Column(s)
    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, //<<<< The respective TO View(s) to populate
    0 //<<<< see documentation but 0 will very likely suffice
);
```

as a replacement for :-

```
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
```

The `onItemSelected` method of the Spinner gets passed 2 pertinent values as the 3rd and 4th parameters/arguments. The 3rd is the position of the selected item, the 4th is the id (if using a Cursor Adapter).